# Google play disappeared from my phone

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-fit

While uninstalling some app I may have accidentally uninstalled Google play app.

But even then I have updated Google play app before and while uninstalling it should remove only updates from my phone not the complete app. I should have been able to use default app.
But I am unable to do so.

Yesterday while clicking app's icon it was showed an error, that app isn't installed.
I tried to find it on my app library but it's not there.

What should I do?

I am using Samsung galaxy fit (GT-S5670)

Comment: Try rebooting. As per you your phone is not rooted and its not possible to delete system app without root.

Comment: @roxan I tried but still no luck

Comment: I have posted link for downloading apk as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, downloading and installing the APK should work as long as you have the Google Framework Services -- basically if the Market worked before, then it will again unless you removed system services.  (Those can be replaced as well but it's more hassle).

Comment: How can I check I have system services or not?

Answer (score 3):

As @Matthew Read suggested I search for an apk over net and found one.

Here is a link: [Google Play Store 3.9.16](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/11/download-latest-google-play-store-3-9-16-with-new-ability-to-remove-apps-from-the-all-apps-list/)

Note: After installing apk to your device if app started force closing

1. Clear data from app i.e go to settings->manage app->play store->clear data
2. If it is still force closing reboot your device

This works for me hope works for others as well

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted, then you of course have a chance that an app could have flashed something that could remove the GAPPS and Google FrameWork Services, but if you don't know what I am talking about then your phone is not rooted, and you simply need to download Google Play Store.
On the other hand, if you are missing GAPPS, then you can re-flash it depending on your version of Android: http://goo.im/gapps/

Comment: No my phone was not rooted. I checked the link you provided but I don't understand how to download and which one.